# Open swriter password protected file from command line?

Tags: command-line, libreoffice

Is there a way to open a password protected swriter file(.odt) from the command line? Using LibreOffice.

Comment: Openoffice or libreoffice? (Although it is not possible with either, there is an open bug-report / enhancement request for libreoffice at least...)

Answer (score 0):

You can't directly do this, although there is an enhancement-tagged request on the LibreOffice bug tracker for this feature, and it is as-yet unimplemented

In the meanwhile, you can do this by running a macro with the `loadComponentFromURL` function with the `Password`  property passed into it. [Documentation to do this is present on their website](https://wiki.openoffice.org/wiki/Documentation/DevGuide/OfficeDev/Handling_Documents#MediaDescriptor).

The macro then created can be run by using:

```
soffice filename macro:///path/to/macro
```

Comment: I found this, but I can not understand how to write the macro. Password
string Password;

Usage Restrictions
    optional
Description
    pasword for loading storing documents 

    It contains a password for loading or storing a component (if necessary). If neither password nor encryption data is specified, loading of a password protected document will fail, storing will be done without encryption. If both are provided, the encryption data is used ( if the filter supports it ).